# Remove reliance on the Android clock entirely and use custom time from server

Tags: java, android, web-services, time

I have an application which records information using a tablet which is sync'ed to a server where reports are then run on the results. The users spend all day using the tablets and travel a lot throughout the day.

The time when the users complete these tasks is crucial to the reports and we have had several occurrences where we can't rely on the device time.

1. The user sometimes manually sets the time to something different on the device in order to look like they have done more work - this happens more than we expected
2. When relying on the time set to 'automatic', the time sometimes jumps around as the users travel between networks
3. When the tablet is initially switched on, sometimes the device time is set to 1970

I have a webservice to get the server time which is not currently used because we can't rely on the users having internet connection because they generally don't have any connection at all due to the nature of the work. However, they sync the data everyday usually, or at least once every few days.

I'd like to create something that gets the server time and counts the time from then on and the app would use this time. Any time they connect, this time will be updated, just to make certain the time is synced. Does anyone have any suggestions as to the best way to do this? Bear in mind that the time that we send up is crucial - it could be the case that if misreported on several occasions, someone could lose their job.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do they do a lot of work saved locally on the tablet? Or is that every piece of work is submitted directly to the server? I ask because if it's the latter, don't use the client time at all, let the server decide.

Comment: I think you have a fine idea of having a webservice return a valid timestamp and then counting forward from there on the client side. Is there something specific about that that you are having trouble with?

Comment: @Corey No they do a lot of local work which needs several timestamps at various points, and they can't sync up until all the work has been completed. As we want to avoid the user knowing that we are monitoring their time, I can't change this procedure.

Comment: @Tim Thanks, I think in theory it sounds good but I'm at a bit of a brick wall as to the best way to implement it so that the app does not have to be run, or the tablet being switched off does not affect it.

Comment: you could try making a ACTION_SHUTDOWN receiver, and an ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETE receiver that way you'll get notified upon shutdown and bootup. at each of those times you can find the system time, and then subtract one from the other upon bootup to glean how long the device was off. But I think even with something like that you'd still want to make a Service that will be nearly always running in background that can sync the time with your server on a more regular basis just incase anything gets off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left this unfinished, but have now implemented a solution.

I've created a Service which runs in the background, and downloads the date at intervals from a webservice, and uses a Timer to increment the time in between calls to the webservice.

Further to this, I use GPS to get the current time and date, and it uses this if possible, and if not then it uses this internal clock.

The time should be right most of the time, in theory!

Answer (score 1):

Android do have 3 different kind of timer...
[SystemClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html)

One of them will be useful to you,[uptimeMillis()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis%28%29)

Once the app starts, save the current uptimeMillis... when the app ends.. you could get the difference from "uptimeMillis() - oldUpTimeMillisThatWasStored"...

Android do sent a broadcast when the time or timezone is changed... 
And if you have a broadcast receiver which catches for these changes from manifest file...
you will know when the time is changed (even if you app is not running)..

[ACTION_TIME_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_CHANGED)

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a look into this and post my final solution

Answer (score 0):

You need persistent internet connection. Otherwise you have to rely on client time which can be modified as you already mentioned. You may be able to track the changes, but only as long as the app is running which can easily be faked by disabling the app (`Settings -> Apps`) before changing the time.

Scenario:

- User completes task, client time gets stored
- User modifies time
- Device gets internet and syncs with server, telling him its current time and the task so server can calculate tasks "real" completion time. <-- ERROR